# Writing C# code to send an email with office 365

Tags: c#, email, office365

This seems like it should be simple to me, but I cannot get it to work.  I can easily send emails with code like this:

```
    [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
    public static void sendEmail(string toEmail, string toName, string subject, string body)
    {

        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("TizzyFoe@MyCompany.com", "Mr Tizzy Foe");
        const string UserName = "TizzyFoe@MyCompanyInc.com";
        const string password = "ThisIsMyRealPassword";
        const string host = "smtp.office365.com";

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmail, toName));
        msg.From = from;
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = body;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        //client.Credentials = (System.Net.ICredentialsByHost)System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        //client.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, password);
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = host;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(msg);

    }
```

But putting my password into code like that is bad for a variety of obvious reasons.

So what I want to do is say, okay this program is running on my laptop and I am logged in as me.  So shouldn't the program be able to access my credentials. And you can see i commented out two failed attempts to do just that:

```
        //client.Credentials = (System.Net.ICredentialsByHost)System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        //client.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

both of those result in this exception:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not
>   authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Maybe my program can only access some encrypted version of my credentials which cannot be passed to the office365 server?  I have kind of a working knowledge of security concepts, but this is getting over my head.

I feel like this can't possible be that difficult.  I know there are applications which can send automated emails through office 365.  Right now, I'm just testing my code as a console app, but my thinking was ultimately I'd create a windows service to run it.  Maybe the windows service would be able to pass credentials?

Comment: DefaultCredentials means the current user's Windows account. Set `client.UseDefaultCredentials =false ` to use a username/password combination

Comment: Changing that value had no outcome on the behavior.  When I specify my name and password and email is sent regardless of whether that is true or false.  And if i use System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials, then an email is not sent.

Comment: I think you confuse the different types of credentials. When you use `DefaultCredentials` your *Windows Account* is used, not your username/password. This will work only if the mail server runs in the same domain as your account, or in a trusted domain. .NET doesn't decrypt and send your password, it send an account token. That's no different than, say, accessing a file share on a server. The Office 365 account has nothing to do with your local account, even if parts of the full account names are the same eg: `myname@outlook.com` vs `MYDOMAIN\myname`

Comment: You've lost me... does this information lead to a solution to the problem?  If so, how should I set the relevant parameters (UseDefaultCredentials and Credentials)?

Comment: My Office 365 account and my local windows account are the same, at least in so far as the user name and password are the same.  If I press control alt delete and change my password, I'll need to use the new password at outlook.office.com.  But it does make sense to me that the accounts might be different behind the scenes... When i got to that website it can't auto log me on based on the fact that i'm already logged into windows.  Maybe its just not possible to get into office 365 without sending a decrypted password... but if that's the case there still must be some solution.